# Why I can not see the rstudio in navigator?

Tags: anaconda

I have install rstudio in conda. why I can not see the rstudio in navigator?
I want to start rstudio in navigator? thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the top bar I can see that "applications on base (root)".

Is base (root) the environment you created for RStudio? I strongly assume it is not. Choose the right environment in the drop-down menu.